# Formatting multiplication table f# output

Tags: f#, grid, multiplication

I am trying to create a N x M multiplication table program using f# where the n and m values are specified by the user and the table is calculated and stored in a 2D array and displayed on the console.

Any help would be much appreciated on getting my array to be displayed in a format similar to:

[image: Desired Output]

as opposed to the one in my program

[image: Current Output]

My Source Code is

```
open System

let func() =
        let multiplication  n m = Array2D.init n m (fun n m -> n * m)


        printf "Enter N Value: "
        let nValue = Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.Parse

        printf "\nEnter M Value: "
        let mValue = Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.Parse

        let grid = multiplication nValue mValue 


        printfn "\n\n%A" grid

func()
```

Also I would like to know how I can get my values to start from 1 as opposed to 0.

Any help much would be much appreciated as I'm a beginner in F#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you gotta do is add 1 to n and m before multiplying them together, such as

```
let multiplication  n m = Array2D.init n m (fun n m -> (n + 1) * (m + 1))
```

However we do have some parenthesis madness here, you could refactor it as following:

```
let myMultFunction n m = (n + 1) * (m + 1)
let multiplication n m = Array2D.init n m myMultFunction
```

The formatting would be a bit trickier, and using for loops is kinda cheating, and not very F#, but given we are using 2d arrays which aren't functional in nature i figured I could sneak this by ;)

```
printfn "A multiplication table:"
printf "   "
for col in 0 .. mValue - 1 do
    printf "%d\t" (col + 1)

printfn ""
for row in 0 .. nValue - 1 do
    for col in 0 .. mValue - 1 do
            if col = 0 then
                    printf "\n%d| " (row + 1)
            printf "%d\t" grid.[row, col]
```

Comment: Thanks, That's worked perfectly :) Any advice on how to format the table?

Answer (score 6):

Formatting output, like any UI task, usually turns out to be surprisingly tricky. This case is no exception.

The idea would be this:

1. Figure out how wide the "cells" of the table should be.
2. Build each row by concatenating together numbers converted to string and padded to the cell width.
3. Prepend the first row.
4. Concatenate all rows separating them with a newline character.

First, let's see how we can figure out the width of the "cell". What is the widest number in the table? Assuming both `n` and `m` are positive, the widest number would be `n*m`, obviously. So, we can calculate the width of the cell like this:

```
let cellWidth = (n*m) |> string |> String.length
```

Similarly, the very first (leftmost) column would be as wide as the biggest number in it, which is `n`:

```
let firstColWidth = n |> string |> String.length
```

Now, let's make ourselves a function that would take a number and left-pad it with spaces to the required width:

```
let pad totalWidth (value: obj) = 
    let s = string value
    if s.Length >= totalWidth then s
    else (String.replicate (totalWidth-s.Length) " ") + s
```

This function is easy to follow: if the string is already over the maximum, just return it, otherwise prepend `(totalWidth-s.Length)` spaces to it.

With this function in hand, we can format a row of our grid:

```
let formatRow rowIdx =
    let cells = [for colIdx in 0..m-1 -> grid.[rowIdx,colIdx] |> pad cellWidth] // Each cell in this row padded to `cellWidth`
    let firstCol = (rowIdx+1) |> pad firstColWidth  // Leftmost column - just the row index itself padded to `firstColWidth`
    let wholeRow = firstCol :: cells  // Whole row consists of the leftmost column plus subsequent cells
    String.concat " " wholeRow
```

Similarly, format the topmost row:

```
let firstRow = 
    let cols = [for col in 1..m -> col |> pad cellWidth]
    let firstCol = " " |> pad firstColWidth
    let wholeRow = firstCol :: cols
    String.concat " " wholeRow
```

Look how similar these functions are: the only difference is `grid.[rowIdx,colIdx]` vs. `col`. Why don't we generalize that?

```
let formatRowWith firstCell getCell =
    let cells = [for colIdx in 0..m-1 -> getCell colIdx |> pad cellWidth]
    let firstCol = firstCell |> pad firstColWidth
    let wholeRow = firstCol :: cells
    String.concat " " wholeRow

let formatRow rowIdx = formatRowWith (rowIdx+1) (fun c -> grid.[rowIdx,c])
let firstRow = formatRowWith " " (fun c -> c+1)
```

Finally, format each row, prepend the first, and concatenate them all together:

```
let rows = [0..n-1] |> List.map formatRow
let allRows = firstRow :: rows
String.concat "\n" allRows
```

The final code:

```
let formatGrid (grid:_[,]) =
    let n, m = grid.GetLength 0, grid.GetLength 1
    let cellWidth = (n*m) |> string |> String.length
    let firstColWidth = n |> string |> String.length

    let pad totalWidth (value: obj) = 
        let s = string value
        if s.Length >= totalWidth then s
        else (String.replicate (totalWidth-s.Length) " ") + s

    let formatRowWith firstCell getCell =
        let cells = [for colIdx in 0..m-1 -> getCell colIdx |> pad cellWidth]
        let firstCol = firstCell |> pad firstColWidth
        let wholeRow = firstCol :: cells
        String.concat " " wholeRow

    let formatRow rowIdx = formatRowWith (rowIdx+1) (fun c -> grid.[rowIdx,c])
    let firstRow = formatRowWith " " id

    let rows = [0..n-1] |> List.map formatRow
    let allRows = firstRow :: rows
    String.concat "\n" allRows
```

Answer (score 0):

I shamelessly copied some parts of Fyodor Soikin's excellent answer but changed the remainder to make the code more "functional" and shorter, albeit less clear to those with an "imperative" bent.

```
let pad totalWidth (value: obj) = 
    let s = string value
    if s.Length >= totalWidth then s
    else (String.replicate (totalWidth - s.Length) " ") + s

let formatGrid (grid:_[,]) =
    let n, m = grid.GetLength 0, grid.GetLength 1
    let cellWidth = (n*m) |> string |> String.length
    let firstColWidth = n |> string |> String.length

    let frow str (rw: int []) = (Array.fold (fun s i -> s + (pad cellWidth i)) str rw) + "\n"
    let firstRow = frow ("\n" + pad (firstColWidth+2) "") [|1..m|]
    let folder str i = str + (frow ((pad firstColWidth (i+1)) + "| ") grid.[i, 0..])

    List.fold folder firstRow [0..(n-1)]

let a2d = array2D [[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]]
formatGrid a2d
```

The output is:

```
val it : string = "
   123
1| 123
2| 456
"
```

Comment: List comprehensions are perfectly functional, there is nothing imperative about them. There is this tendency among many aspiring programmers to confuse "functional" with "hard to understand". Do not fall prey to it.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - That is why I put "functional" inside quoteation marks.